# Accuracy and prediction Classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, decision-tree, text-classification

I have trained LSTM AND decision tree on my data set (type of text classification). I have used K-cross fold validation with k=10.

Decision tree accuracy 61%
LSTM accuracy 90%

Now when I predict on totally unseen data then decision tree predicts more well and good as compared to LSTM.

Why it happens? If LSTM accuracy is more then why decision tree performs more well on unseen data as compare to LSTM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LSTM model may have greater accuracy than a decision tree when training, but the fact that it doesn't generalize well to unseen data, indicates that the LSTM is overfitting to the training data. Try adjusting the train-validation split and batch size to see if that improves your models.

The validation loss during training would indicate which model is better. You can also try using random forests (cluster of decision trees) which has been known to give better results than one decision tree alone